# Django template html variable inside a variable

Tags: django, templates, django-queryset

In my views i created a variable passing in the context that looks like this

```
{13: {112: 33.333333333333336, 120: 66.66666666666667, 125: 66.66666666666667}, 14: {110: 20.0, 111: 20.0, 113: 20.0, 121: 40.0, 126: 40.0}}
```

In my template i am inside a loop from questions, and want to assign this values to answers inside the question:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <div class="ui basic padded segment left aligned">
        <h4 class="ui header">
            Question {{ forloop.counter }} / {{ questions|length }}: {{ question.prompt }}
        </h4>
        <ul>
            {% for option in question.answer_set.all %}
            <li> {{ forloop.counter }}) {{option.text}}: 
                 {{ ans.{{ question.pk }}.{{ option.pk }} }} %.
                
                {{ ans.13.120 }} 
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

If I use {{ ans.13.120 }} it works, but is not dynamic.... I want a way to use variables inside the {{ }}... something like: {{ ans.(question.pk).(option.pk) }}...

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show your models and how `ans` is defined in your view?

Comment: No, Django intentionally makes this hard in an attempt to separate the logic and presentation layers (Such logic should be part of the _view_). A need to do so implies that your view is not passing data in a proper format to your template.

Comment: @IainShelvington, the ans, is basically the dict of dict i showed in the top.

Comment: @Jan and that dict is defined manually? If you generate it from some queries you should be able to combine it with the answer_set

Comment: @IainShelvington, yes, that was my first approach, but for some reason, the argument was not passing... so i have to find a work around...  I even asked this on a separatted question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891569/django-views-passing-a-variable-thru-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do it in templates level you can make custom tag for it and passing the dictionary and the key then you will get the value

Comment: I managed to do a custom_tag with a value and an argument of question.pk and option.text respectively, and it worked! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should do that work in the view. Avoid writing logic in templates.